# tfpt teamproject creation fails for service account but works for user account

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

TFS team project creation using TFPT does not work for SERVICE account but it works well for a user account.

why does it expect user account and what are the actual permissions required for tfpt?

Comment: Are you using the `TFPT  CreatTeamproject

                             /collection:uri
                             /teamproject:"project name" ...` command to create the team project?

Comment: yep, I also added /verbose switch. It throws this message "Validation Settings started"  and then keep on throwing Windows security message box which asks for user name and password . Even if I supply the correct credentials , it still keep on popping up credentials.

Answer (score 0):

If your service account is not a member of the **Project Collection Administrators Group**, get added as one.

To create team projects you must have the **Create new projects permission** set to **Allow**.

Update

[image]

Comment: Yes,it is already member of Project Collection Administrators Group which already has Create new projects permission set to Allow.

Comment: Which error did you get when you use the service account?

Comment: But still it is not working through a IIS website. IIS website is created and has authenticated with the service account. In the website click of a button executes tfpt CreatTeamproject /collection:uri ...... and it fails to work :(

Comment: Unexpected error occurred.
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {A2FA2136-EB44-4D10-A1D3-6FE1D63A7C05} failed due to the following error: 80070005 Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerTools.CommandLine.TeamProjectCreator.CreateProject()

Comment: Did you mean if you change the authenticated of the IIS wibsite to a user account. Then  the command should work. Also double check the account of Microsoft Team Foudation Sever Application Pool in IIS manager have the ability to use tfpt create team project command. Detail see my update.

Comment: IIS Website application pool is authenticated with Service account(NOT user account) -this can not be changed as per policy.So now how can service account (configured in IIS website) can execute the TFPT to create team project.?

Comment: Even after providing all access permissions to service account, it still does not create team project using TFPT commandline.

Comment: yep, I also added /verbose switch. It throws this message "Validation Settings started" and then keep on throwing Windows security message box which asks for user name and password . Even if I supply the correct credentials , it still keep on popping up credentials